# Android custom action bar

Tags: android, android-actionbar

I have a problem that is I add the custom action bar in app, but the action bar view has a gap(the red circle position, in the link's picture).

[image]

MainActivity code:

```
public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main_layout);

        getSupportActionBar().setCustomView(R.layout.actionbar_layout);
        getSupportActionBar().setDisplayShowCustomEnabled(true);

    }
}
```

actionbar_layout code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="#0146A3">
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/abr_title"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:singleLine="true"
        android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
        android:textSize="26sp"
        android:text="Title"
        tools:text="Title"/>
</RelativeLayout>
```

But not use android support library, this problem does not occur.("MainActivity extands ActionBarActivity" change to "MainActivity extands Activity", and "getSupportActionBar() change to getActionBar()")

Comment: Just update your theme in style.xml  <style name="AppBaseTheme"  parent="@android:style/Theme.Holo.Light">

Comment: Try  above this . tell me if works or not ?

Comment: Thank you, but It not work.

Comment: In https://developer.android.com/training/basics/actionbar/styling.html say  the support library action bar style that only can use the "Theme.AppCompat" style.

Answer (score 0):

set Actionbar background using style.xml

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="AppBaseTheme">
        <item name="android:actionBarItemBackground">@drawable/bg_actionbar_selected</item>

</style>


<style name="action_bar" parent="@android:style/Widget.Holo.Light.ActionBar.Solid.Inverse">
        <item name="android:background">@drawable/yourBackgound or color</item>
</style>
```

Answer (score 0):

Let me suggest another way to do that:
Step 1:
Hide your actionbar.
Use this theme for the activity.

```
 android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar"
```

step2:
     Use a custom relative layout as actionbar

```
    <RelativeLayout
                    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_height="60dp"
                    android:background="#009ACD">
           </RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: Can you please mention the error here.I have checked this and got no error.